# Change Cell-Reference in excel-like Formula-String with javascript / jquery

Tags: jquery, excel-formula

i 'am searching for a solution to this Problem:
i have created a jquery based spreadsheet with calculation features and it works nice. Now i want to copy a given formlua to the next rows and to update the cell-references in that formula.
Example: formula in row1 = if(and(A1=0;B1=0);0;A1+B1)
The Copy of this formula to row2 should be:if(and(A2=0;B2=0);0;A2+B2)
Simply replacing the Numbers will result "if(and(A2=2;B2=2);2;A2+B2)" and the copied formula is not right. Has anybody an idea?
Very thanks, Bernd from Germay

This is my current solution:

```
        function createNewFormula()
        {
            var rowNew = $('#copyto option:selected').attr('value');    //the targetRow
            var exp = /(?:\w[0-9]+)/g;                                  //searchPattern
            var formula = $('#formula2').val();                         //current formula
            var arrMatches = formula.match(exp);                        //array of Matches
            var startIndexOf=0;                                         //startposition in current formula
            $.each(arrMatches,function(key,val){
                var idx = formula.indexOf(val,startIndexOf);
                //set new startPositon in current formula
                startIndexOf = idx;
                //replace the number in new Cell-Reference
                var valNew = val.replace(/(?![A-Za-z])\d+/g,rowNew);
                //replace part of current formula with new Cell-Reference
                formula = formula.replace(formula.substring(idx,idx+val.length),valNew);
            });

            //output to an input-element for test
            $('#formulaNew').val(formula);

        }
```

The second idea:

```
        //create a new string-method replaceAll
        String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replacewith) {
            var currentformula = this;
            return currentformula.split(find).join(replacewith);
        };            
        //create a function to check if a substring in formula is a letter
        //like A,B,C....
        function isLetter(formulapos) {
          return formulapos.length === 1 && formulapos.match(/[A-Za-z]/i);
        }
        //and use this in the following to replace the cell-references
        function createNewFormula()
        {
            var rowNew = $('#copyto option:selected').attr('value');    //the targetRow                
            var exp = /\d+/g;                                           //match all munbers
            var formula = $('#formula2').val();                         //current formula to copy
            var arrMatches = formula.match(exp);                        //array of matches
            var startIndexOf=0;                                         //startposition for indexOf-method
            $.each(arrMatches,function(key,val)
            {
                var idx = formula.indexOf(val,startIndexOf);            //set position
                var fsubstr = formula.charAt(idx-1);                    //prev. Pos.
                startIndexOf=idx;
                var isletter = isLetter(fsubstr);                       //is letter at prev. Pos.
                if(isLetter(fsubstr)!==null)
                {
                    //insert a placeholder on the numbers in current formula
                    formula = formula.replace(formula.substring(idx,idx+val.length),'#');
                }
            });
           //replace all placeholders with the new row-Number
           formula = formula.replaceAll('#',rowNew);
           $('#formulaNew').val(formula); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change a little the regex to only change the cell names, for example:

```
var valNew = val.replace(/([A-Z])\d+/g,"$1"+rowNew);
```

Of course this won't help in some cases where you need a cell to never change, but in this case it should work.

Comment: Thank you, for your Answer it helped me to realize the final solution,
but i had trouble with that on longer formulas by example this one:

if(and(A1=0;b1=0);if(A1<AB10;AB1;D1);sum(A1:E1))

Comment: yes if there are cells you have to change and other that shouldn't be changed it's quite hard to do this with the current code. It would be helpfull if the formula had a different notation for cells that can change and cells that musn't be changed.